# Lightning app in managed package not accessible

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I created a managed package with a Lightning app in it, but when I try to access it, it says: "URL No Longer Exists ..."
My Domain is created, changing the namespace in the url from the actual package namespace to c makes no difference.

Any help?

Regards

Answer (score 3):

Did you mark your app as access="GLOBAL"?